# Subtract Amount From Cell Until It Reaches 0 multiple reminding amount

Tags: excel, loops, excel-formula, vba

My formula below subtracts a cell until it reaches zero, and moves to the next one.  The subtraction is based on the value “B”. Each time the formula comes across the value “B”, this action is performed.

**Question:** I have been trying to advance this to formulae, in that each time “B” is found that cell is minuses until zero and those amount multiple by the adjacent price. 
could you please provide me with a formula which does this ?

**Example:** when it comes across the first B the full value of 100 x 10 will be multiplied and the reminder 50 will be multiplied by 15 i.e. 50 x 15 price of the next A. These values will be summed.

[image]

> =MAX(SUMIF($A$2:A2,"A",$B$2:B2)-SUMIF($A$2:$A$10,"B",$B$2:$B$10),0)

The reminder of the 50 is coming from the difference between the B 150 - A 100 , which leaves 50 to be still absorbed .

Further Calculation for explanation:

[image]

[image]

Apologies thats meant to say calculation of **6000**

Comment: your question is a statement, not a question. Your example will need to be much clearer. What is this "remainder 50" you talk about?

Comment: @oldUgly the reminder 5o is between the 150 - 100 = 50.

Comment: This operation is happening until the full amount of B is absorbed.

Comment: @oldUgly question has been updated

Comment: Can't get you. 1) Which is your data? I guess columns A, B and C. 2) Where comes your Answer ($1,750) from? Please explain better what you want to achieve.

Comment: Posting a good explanation is very helpful in many ways, mainly two: i) encourage others for posting a response, and ii) usually help the proposer to clarify his own problem: many times the effort for being more clear make the problem disappear.

Comment: But you have 350 of A. Why are you choosing to ignore the second A?

Comment: @OldUgly i didnt not ignore the second A. There is only 150 of B. Therefore we need to absorb  50 of that only. The reminder of the second we be used the next time we come across B.

Comment: This is more like a stocking system . A is what we buy , and B is our Sells. Once an amount is absorbed its no longer in stock

Comment: @CMArg i will provide a better detailed explanation of the process i am trying to achieve.

Comment: @OldUgly i have add an explanation to my question , thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still very unclear. What does "My formula below subtracts a cell until it reaches zero" mean? Also, as OldUgly pointed out, it seems that you are ignoring the second A. Since we can't understand each other, take a look at the code below and try to rewrite it yourself to fit your needs. It assumes the data is in a sheet named "Data", and that there is a button (`Button1`) to run the code.

```
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim QtyNumberA, QtyNumberB, QtyNumberRem As Integer

Sub Button1_Click()
lLastRow = Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row 'Rows with data, starting 2nd row (titles in the first)
QtyNumberA = 0 'Variable for storing quantities of A
QtyNumberB = 0 'Variable for storing quantities of B
QtyNumberRem = 0 'Variable for storing quantities remaining

For i = 2 To lLastRow 'scan all rows with data
    If (Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value = "A") Then
        QtyNumberA = QtyNumberA + Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value
    ElseIf (Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value = "B") Then
        QtyNumberB = QtyNumberB + Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value
        QtyNumberRem = QtyNumberA - QtyNumberB
        Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 6) = QtyNumberRem
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: i have add an explanation to my question above. Thanks for the help

Comment: If the substraction has to be sequential, I would create al array for storing Quantity:Price pairs of A (ex.: `ArrayA=((100,10),(250,15),....`) and each time a B is found I would substract from the first element of ArrayA. If B Quantity is greater than first element, shrink ArrayA by eliminating first element and set the (original) second element (now the first one) as the remaining quantity.